# R: combine summary of multiple csv files into one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, summary, lapply

I have a directory with many csv files. I want to read them into then create a summary of a column into one data frame.

```
getSummary<-function(df){
   summary(df$Names)
}

filenames<-list.files(path, pattern="*.csv", full.names=T)
ldf<-lapply(filenames, read.csv, header=T)
results<-lapply(ldf, getSummary)
```

It is returning results as follows:

```
print(results)
[[1]]  a   b   c  d
      100  2   3  4
[[2]]  a   b   c  d
      97   4   2  6
```

What I want is something like this

```
filename  a   b   c   d
1.csv    100  2   3   4
2.csv     97  4   2   6
```

Can someone help??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want `do.call(rbind,results)`. But that will only work if each component has at least one of each letter (i.e. all the columns must be present in each). If not you could use `rbind.fill` from **plyr** instead.

I'd also suggest that `table` is a safer function to be using for this purpose than `summary`.